# Не отображается фавикон при пересылке URL в Скайпе

Tags: wordpress

Нужна помощь.
Есть сайт:
https://evroflag.by/
Он сделан на вордпресе.
На нём, как видно, установлен фавикон.
Но по какой-то причине, если делиться ссылкой в скайпе, кастомный фавикон не передаётся, а вместо него отображается фавикон вордпресса.
Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: Передаётся не фавикон, опенграф https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/open-graph/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте прописать

```
<link rel="icon" href="url facvicon(ссылка на favicon)" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="url facvicon(ссылка на favicon)" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="url facvicon(ссылка на favicon)g" />
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это не имеет отношения  к ВП и никак не решает проблему ТСа.